# How can i use javascript backticks?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

i am facing issue when using backticks , The browser show it string,

example:

```html
<h2>${item.title}</h2>
```

Output:
${item.title}

Comment: You probably need to look into a Javascript template engine (Handlebars, EJS) or into a front-end framework. You are trying to use template string (the backticks) into pure HTML, this won't work. 

You can read more about template strings here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Add 3 backticks before and after the code in their own lines to format the code on SO. Please read the [help] pages and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where to using this. but simply you can use backticks like this.

In HTML

```
<div id="title"></div>
```

In Javascript

```js
const titleTag = `<h2>${item.title}</h2>`;

const element = document.getElementById("title");

element.innerHTML = titleTag;
```